# I get 'Errors were encountered while processing: steam_latest.deb' installing Steam

Tags: games, steam

```
makmoonish@makmoonish-Satellite-L655D:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.debSelecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 195097 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking steam-launcher (from steam_latest.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'steam_latest.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz' to '/usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam_latest.deb
```

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install curl` fixed it for me.

```
dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
w1z@cloudy:~/Downloads$ ls
steam_latest.deb
```

After installing curl:

```
w1z@cloudy:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 123 kB of archives.
After this operation, 313 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main curl amd64 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 [123 kB]
Fetched 123 kB in 1s (116 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 173928 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.35.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.35.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up curl (7.35.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up steam-launcher (1.0.0.48) ...
```

Comment: In my case it was also a dependency issue but it was python-apt instead of curl

Answer (score 3):

> unexpected end of file or stream

It means that your copy is incomplete or corrupted. Redownload the package again from the source, and if you can, do a checksum to verify that is sane.

```
md5sum steam_latest.deb
```

Answer (score -3):

It is becuase you newer has update.
pu in the console.

For open a console CTRL+ALT+T

**$ sudo apt-get update**

other way is using the update program

after it try to try tu start steam agine o reinstal it

Comment: Please read the chunk of text, it clearly says *unexpected end of file* whereas it the error that throws when the "file" is incomplete.

Comment: This really doesn't work.