# Cannot install ubuntu 14.04 packages

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt

I have tried to install network-manager because after 13.05.2016 updates broke it. Anyway, there is few issues. I have downloaded from another computer network-manager `network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb` and I have transfer it in ubuntu machine and when I try install it, it throws these errors: 
Well, couldn't upload picture so, here the error message by typing

```
    Selecting previously unselected package network-manager.
(Reading database ... 437422 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
 network-manager depends on libmm-glib0 (>= 0.7.991); however:
  Package libmm-glib0:amd64 is not installed.
 network-manager depends on dnsmasq-base; however:
  Package dnsmasq-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 network-manager
```

Then I downloaded those packages and transfer them in ubuntu machine and when I try install them. Errors are these:

Error when try install lidmm:

```
(Reading database ... 437460 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Error when try install dns:

```
(Reading database ... 437460 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dnsmasq-base_2.68-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq-base (2.68-1ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive dnsmasq-base_2.68-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/sbin/dnsmasq' to '/usr/sbin/dnsmasq.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dnsmasq-base_2.68-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

After 13.05.2016 updates Ubuntu started throw errors all the time. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: And what are the error messages?

Comment: I'm trying add the error messages

Comment: @Videonauth error messages edited in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get 'Errors were encountered while processing: steam\_latest.deb' installing Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332168/i-get-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-steam-latest-deb-installing-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package files `libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb` and `dnsmasq-base_2.68-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` are corrupted. Please ensure that they were transferred correctly and try again.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I got my Ubuntu machine to work perfectly once again.